# Add Multiply By to a number in a new line, Python

Tags: python

```
tstep1= 8
tstep2=10
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 587:
           f.write(str(tstep1))
        elif i==607:
           f.write(str(tstep2))
        else:
           f.write(line)
```

This code is working now and adding the numbers to the line. However, I am trying to add multiplication by * 31 to the number. So instead of having 8 and 10, the file will have 8*31, and 10*31?
I appreciate your help and Thanks in advance 
Best Regards

Comment: Do you want the output to be the text `8*31` or the text `248`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh , I want the output to be 8*31, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `f.write(str(tstep1))` with `f.write(str(tstep1) + "*31")`.
Same goes for `tstep2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tstep1= 8
tstep2=10
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 587:
           f.write(str(tstep1) + '*31\n')
        elif i==607:
           f.write(str(tstep2) + '*31\n')
        else:
           f.write(line)
```

You can just concatenate the strings with `+`